# C# console app crashes when called using shortcut

Tags: c#, console, console-application

I have a small C# console application that copy to a server, where it runs just fine.

However, if I call the .exe using a shortcut from another machine, it crashes. Any dependencies are also present on the calling machine.

In the eventview on the calling machine, all I'm getting is:
Faulting module name:

> KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.14393.2189, time stamp: 0x5abdad60
>   Exception code: 0xe0434f4d

Any ideas to help?

Comment: I could *guess* that your application is making assumptions about its current working directory when it starts but it's difficult to say for sure.

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to start it with a shortcut (and from another machine)? Maybe you can circumvent this problem by solving the underlying problem itself. Does the same thing happen when you don't use the shortcut?

Comment: When I start the application locally (as in on the server where the .exe resides), it runs just fine.  For reasons beyond my control, the .exe must reside on this server, but be callable (using shortcut or scheduler) on a different macine.

Comment: the .exe access an oracle database, pulls data, processes it. Nothing complext. Oracle components are present on both machines.

Comment: If you create a console app that doesn't use Oracle and doesn't do anything and copy it up, does it work? Once you have answered that - keep layering on changes. Add Oracle components. Does it work? Lather, rinse, repeat. At some point it will stop working. The last thing you added to the console app is the missing component on the other machine.

Comment: @mjwills I'll try that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The returned exception is an error with permissions - see the following MSDN forum post;

[https://social.msdn.microsoft.com...](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/eccd7901-caac-4d3a-8614-7b743f83dec6/error-code-0xe0434f4d?forum=csharpgeneral)

It surmises that by default .NET security does not allow you to run .NET programs directly from a network share.  The error itself is from a COM object - "Exception from COM object".